# ArrayList Sorting Based on Method

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

I am in need of some help trying to compare 2 `arraylist` and then sorting;  If I am even on the right track.  So here is my problem..

Say `arraylist` 1 contains the objects in which `3` integers adds up to `4` and each integer has to be at least greater or greater/equal to the next number.

So for example, `arraylist` 1 contains `{(2,1,1), (2,2,0), (3,1,0), (4,0,0)}.`

Also each object integers are sorted from greatest to least.

Now I have a take the `(2,1,1)` and send it to a method to perform an algorithm on it.  for each integer place, i need to add 2 to that integer place, and subtract 1 from the rest.  We can call these A event, B event, or C Event.

for example, `(2,1,1)` which these events would be

```
A Event: (4,0,0)

B Event: (3,1,0)

C Event: (3,1,0)
```

Now, my question is because A event produced `(4,0,0)` how would I sort the first `arraylist` to have that number come next and then have `(3,1,0)` but without `(3,1,0)` duplicating.  So after sorting the array, it should be

```
(2,1,1) ( 4,0,0) (3,1,0) (2,2,0)
```

Comment: I was thinking putting the event in a arraylist, and then comparing the first arraylist with the answer arraylist but i am not sure.

Comment: How do you get `B Event: (3,1,0)` and `C Event (3,1,0)`? I understand the `A Event: (4,0,0)`, but got lost after that.

Comment: B event happens when you subtract 1 from 1st position and 1 from third position and add 2 to the second position.  C Event happens when you subtract 1 from 1st position and 2nd position and add 2 to the third position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present your question is not clear to me, but I think I can help point you in the right direction.

Since you said:

> without (3,1,0) duplicating

I'd suggest that to ensure uniqueness of objects in a `Collection` you should consider using a class that implements the `Set` interface (see [Javadoc for Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) for details).

Assuming you are not writing the sorting algorithm yourself you could use a [SortedSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) and then implement the necessary functionality (`Comparable` interface or `Comparator`) so that your objects are sorted in the way you want (the earlier link provides links that describe how to do this).

Hope this helps, and if you could try to make the question more clear I'd be happy to offer some additional pointers.

Here are some of the confusing parts that you could work on:

> each integer has to be at least greater or greater/equal to the next number.

This is confusing because you're giving two conflicting requirements. Is each number strictly greater than the next or is it greater than or equal to the next?

> Also each object integers are sorted from greatest to least.

I'm not sure what you mean by this because you already said that the integers contained in the objects were in a specific order.

> because A event produced (4,0,0) how would I sort the first arraylist to have that number come next

You're not really telling us how the sorting should work. Can you describe the algorithm more - how does it decide the order of the items, how should one item be compared with another?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more precise when asking the question.  So I used a constructor to create the objects.  So in a sense,

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more precise when asking the question.  So I used a constructor to create the objects.  So in a sense,  
{(2,1,1), (2,2,0), (3,1,0), (4,0,0)} are states, and within each state, they are sorted which I define in the constructor.  That is what I meant with each integer has to be from greater or greater than or equal to.  If n = 4, I ran a for loop from 0 - 4, three times to find the integers that add up to 4.  If 0,0,4 is a possibility, I made sure in my for loop that it has to be 4,0,0.  That is what I meant from that.